# jquery javascript validate if visible

Tags: jquery, validation

```
validate:function(section){
        var elements=this.sections.$sections.eq(section).data('elements') //reference elements within this section that should be validated
        var validated=true, invalidtext=["Fill the following areas:\n"]
        function invalidate(el){
            validated=false
            invalidtext.push("- "+ (el.id || el.name))
        }
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            if (/(text)/.test(elements[i].type) && elements[i].value==""){ //text and textarea elements
                invalidate(elements[i])
            }
            else if (/(select)/.test(elements[i].type) && (elements[i].selectedIndex==-1 || elements[i].options[elements[i].selectedIndex].text=="")){ //select elements
                invalidate(elements[i])
            }
            else if (elements[i].type==undefined && elements[i].length>0){ //radio and checkbox elements
                var onechecked=false
                for (var r=0; r<elements[i].length; r++){
                    if (elements[i][r].checked==true){
                        onechecked=true
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (!onechecked){
                    invalidate(elements[i][0])
                }
            }
        }
        if (!validated)
            alert(invalidtext.join('\n'))
        return validated
    },
```

I want to add a control to this function that checks if field is visible or not. I tried to add this to if lines but didnt work;

```
elements[i].style.display=="none"
```

I'm hiding table not input, can that be reason? Is there any other method to add this control?

**EDIT**
Solution:
    elements[i].style.display!=="none"

Comment: The elements[i] should be a jquery collection instead of a standard HTMLElement object in order to call "is" Method

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that `elements` is an array of DOM elements and not jquery objects.  `is` must be called on a jquery object.

```
$(elements[i]).is(":visible")
```

Also note that this returns a boolean, no need to check if it's `== true`.

Comment: Answer still stands if you are using jquery (as your tags imply).  This will work even if you are hiding a parent element.